# Motd is displayed twice or not at all

Tags: server, scripts, ssh, pam, motd

I've been getting this annoying issue where I cannot edit my `/etc/update-motd.d/` files correctly without messing it up. Now for some reason no matter what I do, my motd is displayed twice or not at all. I added a custom script on my raspberry pi before and it works fine(ish) but here it's an absolute mess. For starters there is no `/etc/motd` file, which is what I am used to, but that's just ubuntu being different I suppose. So as I understand there is twice the same line of script in both `/etc/pam.d/login` and `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, which is supposed to update `/run/motd.dynamic` through the use of the scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d/`. With a completely clean installation, this works fine.

I then disabled all the scripts in the `/etc/update-motd.d/` directory by using `sudo chmod -x *` and I added my own script which I performed a +x on. Then I logged out and logged back in: boom, the motd was displayed twice... It's not supposed to display twice and the script doesn't do that either, because running it on it's own displays only once.

I searched and searched. I tried almost all configurations of disabling

```
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
```

in both `/etc/pam.d/login` and `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. Whatever I do, it's ALWAYS displaying either twice or not at all. The only thing that is always without question displayed is the last login time and ip.

I now restored it all back to the original settings. Added all the original files back with proper permissions, disabled my file and now the original prints twice or not at all.

I am completely lost. Is there anyone that can help me?

Comment: Try checking the /etc/ssh/sshd_config for PrintMotd=yes in ssh (Also PrintLastlog)..

After that you could have something in /etc/profile.d/ for interactive sessions.

Comment: I went away from Ubuntu and installed straight Debian, but appear to have the same problem now. Currently sshd_config has yes for printmotd and in pam.d/ssh the motd lines are disabled. It prints twice now. It's a whole mess I can't even begin to describe. If I disable both lastlogin and printmod in sshd_config, then the config hinges entirely on the files in /etc/pam.d and no lastlogin is printed. When I enable both features in both files of pam.d it all prints, and when I disable just one of them, it prints zero times that part

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue duplication of the MOTD on Windows using Powershell Core. The MOTD display as expected when using ssh from the cmd console. But will duplicate if you are using powershell core.

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1253

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1242029)